# MySQL binding multiple parameters to a single query

Tags: mysql, .net, .net-core, dapper

I have a MySql database, and I'm connecting to it from a .Net app using Dapper. I have the following code:

```
await connection.ExecuteAsync(
    "DELETE FROM my_data_table WHERE somedata IN (@data)", 
    new { data = datalist.Select(a => a.dataitem1).ToArray() },
    trans);
```

When I do this with more than a single value, I get the following error:

```
MySqlConnector.MySqlException: 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)'
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible in MySql / Dapper, or do I have to issue a query per line I wish to delete?

Comment: Doens't IN require a comma separated string? so you: string.join(",",datalist.Select(a => a.dataitem1).ToArray())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code was almost fine. You just need to remove the parentheses around the parameter. Dapper will insert those for you:

```cs
await connection.ExecuteAsync(
    "DELETE FROM my_data_table WHERE somedata IN @data", 
    new { data = datalist.Select(a => a.dataitem1).ToArray() },
    trans);
```